# atan2f gives different results with m32 flag

Tags: c, floating-point, 32bit-64bit

I'm porting some code from 32 bit to 64 bit, and ensuring the answers are the same. In doing so, I noticed that atan2f was giving different results between the two.

I created this min repro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void testAtan2fIssue(float A, float B)
{
    float atan2fResult = atan2f(A, B);
    printf("atan2f: %.15f\n", atan2fResult);

    float atan2Result = atan2(A, B);
    printf("atan2: %.15f\n", atan2Result);
}

int main()
{
    float A =  16.323556900024414;
    float B = -5.843180656433105;
    testAtan2fIssue(A, B);
}
```

When built with:

```
gcc compilerTest.c -m32 -o 32bit.out -lm
```

it gives:

```
atan2f: 1.914544820785522
atan2: 1.914544820785522
```

When built with:

```
gcc compilerTest.c -o 64bit.out -lm
```

it gives:

```
atan2f: 1.914544701576233
atan2: 1.914544820785522
```

Note that atan2 gives the same result in both cases, but atan2f does not.

**Things I have tried:**

1. Building the 32 bit version with -ffloat-store
2. Building the 32 bit version with -msse2 -mfpmath=sse
3. Building the 64 bit version with -mfpmath=387

None changed the results for me.

(All of these were based on the hypothesis that it has something to do with the way floating point operations happen on 32 bit vs 64 bit architectures.)

**Question:**

What are my options for getting them to give the same result? (Is there a compiler flag I could use?) And also, what is happening here?

I'm running on an i7 machine, if that is helpful.

Comment: Prinitng with `"atan2f: %.15f\n"` _may be_ insufficiently precise.  Use `"%.16e\n"` or better `"%a\n"` for investigation.

Comment: Why do you expect two different libraries to provide exactly the same results and which sizes has `float` on both platforms? The differences are not that one would worry.

Comment: Note that `1.914544701576233` and `1.914544820785522` differ by 2 bits in the [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)

Comment: There are almost no circumstances where you should depend on two different floating point calculations giving the same result.

Comment: 32 bit floats are only accurate to 6 or 7 significant figures: not 15.  What is sizeof(float) on the 64-bit system - 4 or 8?

Comment: "options for getting them to give the same result?" --> Report `printf("%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);` for each system.  That _should  not_ make a difference here, but does shed some light on what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier to see in hex notation.

```
void testAtan2fIssue(float A, float B) {
    double d = atan2(A, B);
    printf("        atan2 : %.13a %.15f\n", d, d);
    float f = atan2f(A, B);
    printf("        atan2f: %.13a %.15f\n", f, f);
    printf("(float) atan2 : %.13a %.15f\n", (float) d, (float) d);

    float f2 = nextafterf(f, 0);
    printf("problem value : %.13a %.15f\n", f2, f2);
}

// _ added for clarity
        atan2 : 0x1.ea1f9_b9d85de4p+0 1.914544_797857041
        atan2f: 0x1.ea1f9_c0000000p+0 1.914544_820785522
(float) atan2 : 0x1.ea1f9_c0000000p+0 1.914544_820785522
problem value : 0x1.ea1f9_a0000000p+0 1.914544_701576233
```

---

> what is happening here?

The conversion from `double` to `float` can be expected to be optimal, yet *arctangent* functions may be a few [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) off on various platforms.  The `1.914544701576233` is the next smaller `float` value and reflects the slightly inferior arctangent calculation.

---

> What are my options for getting them to give the same result?

Few.  Code could roll your own `my_atan2()` from an *established* code base.  Yet even that may have subtle implementation differences.  [@stark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034329/atan2f-gives-different-results-with-m32-flag/42034772#comment71243291_42034329)

Instead, consider making code checking tolerant of the minute variations.

Comment: I think the question is asking what flag can make these identical(other than m32)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm working with a legacy code base, so making it tolerant of the minute variations is nontrivial. Alas, guess I'll have to work around the issue.

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus True, using a _flag_ may have been one approach to solve this problem.  Yet I did not see the post as being limited to a simple gcc option change, but more open.